# How to get audio from generator/instrument VST with VST.NET and NAudio?

Tags: c#, .net, audio, midi, vst

I'm trying to write a simple VST host in C# using NAudio and VST.NET. I don't know how to get output audio buffers with generator/instrument VST and pass it to NAudio. Has someone did something like that and can share his/her experience with me?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Perhaps this will help? https://github.com/perivar/AudioVSTToolbox

Comment: Thanks @obiwanjacobi ! This will definitely help me.
Quick question: Why does it only work fine when I compile it with x86 configuration (when I tried x64 configuration VSTs couldn't be loaded), is there a way to compile it with x64 configuration and get it working with 64-bit VSTs?

Comment: If you compile for 64-bit, the plugins also have to be 64-bit. Are they?

Comment: Yeah, I tried compiling for 64-bit and neither 64-bit nor 32-bit plugins worked. I only got dialog saying:
_"Could not load file or assembly 'Jacobi.Vst.Interop, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fa678e13c1efc859' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."_